# How to convert string into type?

Tags: c#

Changetype can not change to type `create<Convert.ChangeType(type)>(type);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Xml.Linq;
//using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Reflection;

namespace FixUtil
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FIXMessage fix = new FIXMessage();
            fix.top1 = "FIXML";
            fix.top2 = "FIXMLMessage";
            XMLUtil go = new XMLUtil(fix);

            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), new XElement("FIXML"));

            XElement top2 = new XElement("FIXMLMessage", null);
            XElement Header = go.createHeader();
            top2.Add(Header);
            XElement ApplicationMessage = go.createApplicationMessage();
            top2.Add(ApplicationMessage);

            XElement order_element = go.createOrder();
            ApplicationMessage.Add(order_element);
            //Order.Add(go.createClOrderID("1968"));

            Order order_instance = new Order();
            order_instance.CIOrdID = "1968";
            order_instance.instrument = new Instrument();
            order_instance.instrument.Symbol = "1171";

            create<Order>(order_element, order_instance);
            //create<Order>(order_element);

            xdoc.Root.Add(top2);
            xdoc.Save("./FIX.xml");
            while (true)
            { }
        }
        //protected static void create<T>(XElement root) where T : new()
        protected static void create<T>(XElement root, T instance) where T : class
        {
            //MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            if (typeof(T).GetProperties().Count() == 0)
                return;
            foreach (PropertyInfo memberinfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                string type = memberinfo.PropertyType.ToString().Split('.')[1].ToString();
                XElement child;
                if (type == "String")
                {
                    root.Add(new XElement(memberinfo.Name, memberinfo.GetValue(instance, null)));
                    //root.Add(new XElement(memberinfo.Name, null));
                }
                else
                {
                    child = new XElement(memberinfo.Name, null);
                    root.Add(child);
                    create(child, memberinfo.GetType());
                    //create(child, instance);
                    //create<Type.GetType(type)>(child);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(memberinfo.Name + " "
                        + memberinfo.PropertyType.ToString().Split('.')[1].ToString() + " "
                    //+ memberinfo.GetValue(instance, null).ToString() + " "
                        + memberinfo.PropertyType);
            }
            return;
        }

        protected static void create(XElement root, dynamic instance)
        {
            //return null;
            //root.Add(new XElement(instance, GetValue(instance, null)));
            //child = new XElement(root, null);
            //create(child);
            //MethodInfo[] methodInfos = instance.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            if(instance.GetProperties().Count() == 0)
                return;
            foreach (PropertyInfo memberinfo in instance.GetProperties())
            {
                string type = memberinfo.PropertyType.ToString().Split('.')[1].ToString();
                XElement child;
                if (type == "String")
                {
                    //root.Add(new XElement(memberinfo.Name, memberinfo.GetValue(instance, null)));
                    root.Add(new XElement(memberinfo.Name, null));
                }
                else
                {
                    child = new XElement(memberinfo.Name, null);
                    root.Add(child);
                    create(child, memberinfo.GetType());
                    //create(child, instance);
                    //create<Type.GetType(type)>(child);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(memberinfo.Name + " "
                        + memberinfo.PropertyType.ToString().Split('.')[1].ToString() + " "
                    //+ memberinfo.GetValue(instance, null).ToString() + " "
                        + memberinfo.PropertyType);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is to change member's type name into type for passing into T of create<T>(type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do with generics is impossible if the type you need is not T.

The value that goes where you are asking for needs to be a generic value or a value known at compile time.

That means your only choice is:

```
create<T>(root);
```

Or:

```
create<PureTypeName>(root);
```

Or adding other generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ChangeType(type)` is not a type parameter.  It's function call.  You have to give a literal type or generic type parameter inside the angle brackets.  You can't use a `System.Type` reference, and you certainly can't use an `object` reference.

Comment: What should i pass into T in Create<T> as there may be another class type into class

Comment: i have already got the type name of member but do not know how to change it into type for passing into <T>

Answer (score 0):

To call this method:

```
create<Person>(xmlDoc);
```

or

```
dynamic obj = create(xmlDoc);
```

and providing an overload of the create function that takes no type. Which is cleaner because now you do not have to know what type will be returned.

Comment: compile error, only assignment, call, decrement and new object expression can be used as a statement

Comment: Can you show us the calling code? You can only call this method from within the class that defines create or one of its descendants.

Comment: Edited, Please see code above

Comment: What line is giving you the compile error?

Comment: And, are you sure you want to strip off the namespace from the type?

Comment: at line create<Type.GetType(type)>(root);  all class in the same namespace

Comment: Sorry, I made a huge mistake. My second solution is wrong. In this case you cannot solve this using generics because at compile time the type is unknown. The only solution that I see is by using `dynamic`. I changed my answer.

Comment: i can not get it, i am new to dynamic, what should return as dynamic? add overload function, could you give your whole success code, i edited code above and make it to show the members' value

Comment: dynamic can be any type and you can call any method, the compiler will not care but at runtime the actual type will be used and available. Just return an object from the create method.